# You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a new command representing a ternary operator

```tex
\newcommand{\ternary}[1][2][3]{\textbf{if} \quad #1 \quad \textbf{then} \quad #2 \quad \textbf{else} \quad #3}
```

Do you see why this error occurs and how it could be fixed?

Comment: The correct syntax to define a macro taking three arguments is `\newcommand{\ternary}[3]{...}`, not `\newcommand{\ternary}[1][2][3]{...}`. Maybe you are mixing it with the plain TeX way which would be `\def\ternary#1#2#3{...}`.

Comment: oh yeah, thank you!

Comment: Consider using the `xparse` package for writing macros, it makes it much easier in my opinion.